# Bootstrap and HTML: how to get first row content centered as full width and second row centered using a 50/50 split

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

I'd like to be able to get a layout using Bootstrap that looks as follows:
[image]

My code is:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">foo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">bar</div>
        <div class="col-6">baz</div>
    </div>
```

Unfortunately, I'm getting something that looks like this (notice that "foo" in row 1 is aligned with "bar" in row 2):

[image]

How do I achieve the desired result?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to only **center** the text on the `.col-12` from the first `.row` which you can easily achieve by simply adding the `text-center` class to that `.col-12` element.
**Note:** the class `text-center` is a `Bootstrap` class.

```css
/** just to visually show the changes */

.col-6,
.col-12 {
  border: 1px solid red
}

.col-12 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">foo</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">bar</div>
    <div class="col-6">baz</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In case you have an `img` not a text on the `.col-12` element, you might simply add the `d-inline-block` and your image should be centered thanks to `text-ce,ter` class that we already applied.

```css
/** just to visually show the changes */

.col-6,
.col-12 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.col-12 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" width="150" class="img-fluid d-inline-block">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">bar</div>
    <div class="col-6">baz</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> **Note:** the use of `d-inline-block` is not *really* required but i used it to ensure cross-browser behavior because each browser might treat the images in a different way. Most of the browsers already set the `display` property of an image to `inline-block`.

> The class `img-fluid` is a `Bootstrap` class that allows to maintain a responsive image. Learn more about [Bootstrap Responsive Images](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/images/) on Bootstrap Docs (BS v4.0).

> Learn more about the [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) property on MDN.

Comment: Thank you, @ths.  This works perfectly.  I see that you've used the `text-center` class (which works for text).  If I had, say, an image or a table, would the `content-center` work for those two use cases?

Comment: @equanimity In the case when you have an image, a quick solution is to add `d-inline-block` to that image and the `text-center` class that we have already will work just fine.

Comment: @equanimity i have updated my answer to include a demo for the case of having an image instead of text.

Answer (score 1):

According to your code to make it center, you can align the text center and that's all.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-12">foo</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row text-center">
        <div class="col-6">bar</div>
        <div class="col-6">baz</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-12 text-center">foo</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">bar</div>
    <div class="col-6">baz</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).